# Refactoring nested TypeScript namespaces into separate files

Tags: typescript

In a rather large application, I've separated code into namespaces. One such namespace has several nested namespaces has grown to be over 900 lines long and I would like to extract each of these nested namespaces into its own file and be able to reference it from the original namespace. Here's a contrived example of how it looks now:

```
/* Bookings.ts */
export namespace Bookings {
    
    // example: Bookings.Status.Complete
    export enum Status {
        Initialized, Created, Complete, Cancelled
    }

    // more code...

    export namespace Inquiry {

        // example: const state: Bookings.Inquiry.FormState = {}
        export interface FormState {
            date?: Date
            organizer?: Partial<Contact>
            location?: Partial<Location>
        }

        // lots more code...
    }

    // more code...
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to extract the `Inquiry` namespace into its own file and be able to reference it from within the `Bookings` namespace, to avoid refactoring all references of `Bookings.Inquiry` to whatever the exported name in the new file is.

```
/* BookingInquiry.ts */
export namespace BookingInquiry {
    
    export interface FormState {
        date?: Date
        organizer?: Partial<Contact>
        location?: Partial<Location>
    }
}
```

And...

```
/* Bookings.ts */
import { BookingInquiry } from '@namespaces/BookingInquiry'

export namespace Bookings {

    // 
    export [somehow] BookingInquiry
}
```

I realize that eventually, this gets converted down to JavaScript, so some concessions must be made, but in the end, I'm hoping there's a way to get this done. I'd rather not have to refactor hundreds of files to accommodate a different namespace and/or file import, and I'd like to keep the `Bookings` namespace as a clean interface to all the related logic. As an aside, none of the other nested namespaces reference anything in other sub-namespaces, but do reference types/enums/interfaces in the parent.

Is there a possible way to do this, or am I doomed to refactor or leave the main file long and unruly?

Answer (score 0):

TypesScript provides [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files) [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces) in order to enable code splitting across multiple files.

The following code will merge `BookingInquiry` as member into `Bookings` namespace. Pay attention to the position of `export namespace BookinInquiry`: it's inside the namespace and not at the top-level, so the file belongs to the global namespace. `export` inside the namespace has nothing to do with module imports: it makes the member public to namespace consumers.

```
/* BookingInquiry.ts */
namespace Bookings {
  export namespace BookingInquiry {
    export interface FormState {
      date?: Date;
      organizer?: Partial<Contact>;
      location?: Partial<Location>;
    }
  }
}
```

Bookings namespace will drop the `BookingInquiry` member and get leaner.

```
/* Bookings.ts */
namespace Bookings {
  // example: Bookings.Status.Complete
  export enum Status {
    Initialized,
    Created,
    Complete,
    Cancelled
  }
  // more code...
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot keep your namespace structure only in `Bookings.ts` - you will also have to re-declare `Bookings` as parent namespace of `BookingInquiry`. That is, because namespaces are considered named [JavaScript object in the *global namespace*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-namespaces) to be consumed via `<script>` and are resolved to `var`. You cannot `import` code from a module into namespaces: if you write `export namespace BookingInquiry` at the top level of a file, TypeScript will treat that file as *module* which you cannot import in `Bookings.ts` namespace. There is no special `import` declaration to import other namespaces, so the parent-child relation has to be made explicit in `BookingInquiry.ts`.

Having said that, I don't really understand why you export your namespaces in the top level, as they are considered to be contained in modules then and create [needless namespacing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing). You'll want to use namespaces for global scripts OR use module resolution, where the latter is the [recommended approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) in most cases:

> Modules provide for better code reuse, stronger isolation and better tooling support for bundling. [...] Starting with ECMAScript 2015, modules are native part of the language, and should be  supported by all compliant engine implementations. Thus, for new projects modules would be the recommended code organization mechanism.

So you can drop the top-level `export` like in the code example (global namespaces) or use modules entirely. PS: If you want to make your namespace leaner by outsourcing types, you can make use of [import types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types).

```
// my-type.d.ts
export type MyType = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
};

// Bookings.ts
namespace Bookings {
 export const foo: import("./my-types").MyType = { foo: "lala", bar: 42 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I decided to just refactor the old fashioned way, what I envisioned is more complicated than it's worth. As for exporting the namespace, I need to in order to expose that code outside its own module. If I omit the export, I can't import anything from within it. I'm not sure about your examples and what you mean by "Needless namspacing", as the link I followed does not represent how my code imports from them.

Comment: Needless namespacing means, that modules already provide an isolated scope them selves (the file), so there is no need to have a namespace inside a module to distinguish names. If you want the code to be  `import`ed from other modules, drop the namespace and export members directly, e.g. `export const foo = 42` instead. From outside, you then just write `import {foo} from "./myFile"`. For a namespace you would write `namespace Wrapper { export const foo = 42 }` and then reference `foo` from outside by writing `Wrapper.foo` (then expected to be a global script var).

Comment: If that's relevant to you: there is also the possibility to publish code in a file as namespace (global script) *and* module (whatever is used by the client) via [UMD](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#umd-modules) module format.